# How to set user specific channel perms discord.py

Tags: python, permissions, discord.py, channel, user-permissions

I am trying to make a support system where users say `;support reason` and then a channel is created with perms for admins and the non admin user to talk and discuss help! This is my code:

```
@command()
  async def support(self, ctx, *, reason = None):
    guildid = ctx.guild.id
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    amount2 = 1
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount2)
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {user}')
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
    perms = channel.overwrites_for(user)
    await channel.set_permissions(user, view_channel=not perms.view_channel)
    await channel.set_permissions(user, read_message_history=not perms.read_message_history)
    await channel.set_permissions(user, send_messages=not perms.send_messages)
    await channel.send(f"{user.mention}")
    supem = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} requested support.", description= "", color=0x00ff00)
    supem.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"``{reason}``")
    supem.set_footer(text=f"Either an admin or support staff will be with you shortly...")
    await channel.send(embed=supem)
```

but I cant get the permissions to work, I want the user to be able to see the channel, send messages, and view message history. Please explain why my permission setting part isnt working. I get no errors, it just doesnt assign the view_channel permissions.

Comment: Help would be greatly appreciated! Please.

Comment: What intents have you enabled?